# In jsp, generating pdf I get a java.lang.IllegalStateException: STREAM

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, jasper-reports

I've been asked to create a report in an existing webapplication (not my own, and I do not have access to its code). I've decided that *JasperReports* was the easiest, since there are many fine examples around...

I've written the sample below, but the browser displays an empty page, no pdf is showing. However, if I refresh the browser page, sometimes the pdf is shown.

```
<%@ page  import="java.io.*"%> 
<%@ page  import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page  import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page  import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@ page  import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@ page  import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@ page  import="javax.servlet.ServletException"%>
<%@ page  import="javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream"%>
<%@ page  import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"%>
<%@ page contentType="application/pdf" %>


    <%
         Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://[server][\instance]:1433;databaseName=[databasename];integratedSecurity=True");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();


        }


        File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("/bespoke/rapport/Planning.jasper"));//your report_name.jasper file
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, conn);


                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
                ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

           %>
```

The exact error I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: STREAM
at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.getWriter(Response.java:616) ~[jetty-6.1.24.jar:6.1.24]
at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:122) ~[servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:na]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:187) ~[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20091210.jar:na]
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:180) ~[jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20091210.jar:na]
```

Now, I know the issue is in the last bits of code.
Problem is, how do I solve this when I am not allowed to add classes to the original program? 
I can only add the *.jasper* file and by gods grace a simple *.jsp* page.
Again, I know it is extremely bad form to add code to a *jsp*, but I am stuck here...

Comment: Normally I obviously would write a servlet to extend the HTTPServlet, however, there is no way to deploy said servlet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my code to the following:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*,net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.*" %>  
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang.time.*" %>  
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.io.*" %>
<%
 String filename = request.getParameter("filename");
 String reporttype = request.getParameter("reporttype");
 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://[servername]\\[instancename];databaseName=[databasename][:portnumber(remove when dynamic port is used)];integratedSecurity=True");
           System.out.println("Connection Established");
 String path = application.getRealPath("/");

 JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path + "/" + filename, null, conn);
 System.out.println("Report Created...");

 OutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();

 JRExporter exporter = null;

 if( "pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
 {
      response.setContentType("application/pdf");
      exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
      exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
      exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
 }
 else if( "html".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
 {
      exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
      exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
      exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
 }
 else if( "xls".equalsIgnoreCase(reporttype) )
 {
      response.setContentType("application/xls");
      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"file.xls\"");

      exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
      exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
      exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
 }
 try 
 {
      exporter.exportReport();
 } 
 catch (JRException e) 
 {
      throw new ServletException(e);
 }
 finally
 {
      if (ouputStream != null)
      {
           try
           {
                ouputStream.close();
           }
           catch (IOException ex)
           {
           }
      }
 }
%>
```

Sad to have to do it this way, but at least it does the trick....

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error yesterday with creating and returning an Excel file in JSP.  You need to remove all the space between your closing (%>) and opening (<%) jsp tags.

Instead of

```
 <%@ page contentType="application/pdf" %>


 <%
  Connection conn = null;
```

Make it

```
 <%@ page contentType="application/pdf" %><%
  Connection conn = null;
```

If you leave space then JSP calls the response.getOutputStream() to create the JspWriter, which you don't want since you need to call response.getOutputStream() yourself to return the binary file.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the trick. I changed my .jsp completely.